# Discrete Sobolev Space and Sobolev Spaces of Banach Space valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

This is a reference request.
Can someone kindly give me some refernce(Books/papers) on

1. **Discrete Sobolev Space** (like we use Discrete $L^p$ spaces of $g\colon\Omega\to\Bbb R $ maps with norm given as summations );
2. Sobolev Spaces of **Banach Space valued Maps** a generalization of $\Bbb R^n$ valued maps).

$W^{m,p}$consisting of $f \colon\Omega\to X $ where $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n $ and $X$ is a Banach space. In general $X$ can be thought of $\Bbb R^d$.

Answer (score 4):

[Reference for 1](http://facpub.stjohns.edu/ostrovsm/sobolev.pdf)

[Reference for 2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/papers/banach.pdf)